# How to connect line segments to form the least number of paths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

I have a list of unordered line segments, some of whose endpoints lie on the same point. How do I connect these segments efficiently to form a minimal amount of paths?

For example, if I have the following lines $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$: `[[0, 0, 2, 2], [4, 0, 2, 1], [2, 2, 4, 0]]` the algorithm should be able to join these three segments into one path $(x, y)$: `[[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 1]]`.

Comment: Can you tell us the context in which you encountered this task?

Comment: This is something that could be very handy for a _traveling salesman_ who wants to minimize travel distance!

Comment: Yes, that's right. The specific application I need this for is for generating code for a 3D printer. A single connected line is a lot faster to traverse because the third axis (which moves a lot slower) doesn't need to be used (and travel distance in general is reduced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this using any algorithm for the traveling salesman problem.  Construct a graph with one vertex per line.  Add an edge of cost 0 from line to another if they share an endpoint (these correspond to extending an existing path).  Add an edge of cost 1 between each other pair of lines (these correspond to starting a new path).  Now find the shortest traveling salesman tour of this graph.  That will correspond to a minimal set of paths that cover all of the lines; the number of lines will be equal to the weight of the traveling salesman tour.  There are standard algorithms and solvers for the TSP.